# Changing a 2way & a 1 way AU light switch to a smart light switch

Tags: smart-switch

I have purchased a 1 gang and a 2 gang smart switch with the back as thi 1st picture.  The attached are the existing wiring points.  Currently the single and 1 of the 2 gang operates the hall and the 2nd of the 2 gang operates the porch.

How to I wire them up?[[image: single switch]] [image: the back of the smart switches]
[image: 2 gang switch]

Comment: Man, lazy electrician. There's obviously enough room for a proper pigtail there...

Comment: It appears that your 1st and 3rd pictures are the same. Did you intend to include a different image for the 3rd, or did you accidentally duplicate it? Either way, please [edit] your post to clean it up. Also, please take the [tour] so you can make the most of this site.

Comment: there's no requirement for pigtails, the Australian switches have clamping terminals suitable for connecting many wires at every terminal point. and a spare terminal just for joining wires (unused here)

Comment: please edit your question to share more of the details of the smart switch, what I can see makes no mention of multi-way switching. and the details of that will be required to set the switch up.

Answer (score 1):

OK, that looks like a typical Australian switch setup.

You have 4 cables:

- two of them are power

  - one is power in
  - the other power out going places unknown
  - these two are the cables the connect to the short red cable that goes between the two switches.
- then you have a cable with three wires that goes to one lamp
- a cable with 4 wires that goes to the other switch of the 2-way,

  - and from there another wire that goes onward to the hallway light.

Unfortunately it doesn't look like the switches you have make provision for multi-way switching, or if they do it's on another page of the instructions.